# How to add Flash support on a PowerPC debian

Tags: debian, adobe-flash, powerpc, iceweasel

I have a PowerBook G4 running Debian.

I followed the instructions from the debian [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer#Installation) but for installation, it just said

> Install flashplugin-nonfree (from section contrib).

I was not sure what that meant, So I just ran

```
apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

But got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package flashplugin-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'flashplugin-nonfree' has no installation candidate
```

here is my `sources.list` - **Edited:**

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official powerpc CD Binary-1 20131215-05:55]/ wheezy main

deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.3.0 _Wheezy_ - Official powerpc CD Binary-1 20131215-05:55]/ wheezy main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: can you provide us the content of /etc/apt/sources.list in here you should have a line for the non free packages that is commented

Comment: @Kiwy, ok I made the addition of the content. What am I looking for in there?

Comment: can you update your `source.list` in your post ?

Comment: @Kiwy, ok updated after I followed your instructions on your last edit.

Comment: well now I pout the exact synthax you should type because `(enventually)` is not to be put in the command line

Comment: The discussion here might be useful: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4008296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New Answer

Sorry I wasn't cautious enought.
On PowerPC there's no official support for Flash your only alternative is a free plugin "[gnash](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gnash)"
`sudo apt-get install gnash browser-plugin-gnash`

---

## Old Answer

To add non free app to your installation source modify the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo 'the_editor_of_your_choice' /etc/apt/source.list
```

<del>edit the line

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main`

to

`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free`</del>

**Edit 2**:
`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main`
or
`deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free`

Then run those line

```
#this is for updating ths list of app available in repository after the update made to your `source.list` file  
sudo apt-get update

# You might want to run this command to upgrade your packages:
sudo apt-get upgrade 

#this is the command to install flash on debian once you activate the nonfree and contrib repositories
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree

#this seems to be the command to update according to the [debian wiki][2]
sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --install
```

And that should do the trick.

Comment: what is the "(eventually)"? I made the modifications and ran the commands but got "Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package flashplugin-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
" Link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/8280152)

Comment: have you try `sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --install`

Comment: the `evantually part` is just to make your packages up to date while update is to refresh the list of application available in `apt-get`

Comment: I ran that and got `sudo: update-flashplugin-nonfree: command not found` so I googled that but only found a [debian forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=72752) with people complaining that it is common problem.

Comment: In your edit, you linked the wiki that I included in my question details but said it had me stuck :/

Comment: well you mentionned typing `sudo apt-get install` I told you to use `sudo update-flashplugin-nonfree --install` which is different.

Comment: @JGallardo sorry I made a mistake in the edit of the `source.list` file

Comment: I tried that and ran the commands and got `sudo apt-get upgrade (eventually)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
` so I just ran the upgrade. Then later i got back `sudo: update-flashplugin-nonfree: command not found
`

Comment: errors when i ran update are at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/JGallardo/8280618)

Comment: Well you can undo any modification to your `source.list` file and Try the free plugon because there no PowerPC flash support. Sorry

Comment: @terdon good old french-english translation thank you for the edit. I'll remind that one.